# iOS Disable popping to root view on pressing tab bar button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem, poptoviewcontroller

I'm looking to disable the functionality of pressing my tab bar and returning to the root view in the navigation hierarchy whilst also keeping this functionality for a button in my navigation bar.

So the only way I want the user to go back to the root view is by pressing the button in the navigation bar and not by tapping the tab bar button.

I've had a look around and tried several solutions but none seem to work as they disable the functionality for both the nav bar button and the tab bar button but not just the tab bar button.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what functionality you're talking about. When you switch tabs in a tab bar controller, it should have no effect on the navigation stack of any of the navigation controllers that are root controllers in a tab. I certainly haven't seen that behavior in my apps. Explain what your controller setup is.

Comment: He doesn't mean switching between tabs, as far as I understand. When you select the currently selected tab (again) in your UITabBarController it automatically pops back to the rootviewController of its navigationController stack. That's the default behavior. And he wants to avoid this. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @croX, yeah, I misunderstood the question. What you describe is the default behavior when you click on the tab you're already on.

Comment: @rdelmar, yes exactly.

Comment: HI guys, yes apologies that wasn't clear. It is when the tab is already selected and pressed again

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Surprised I found this post

Comment: I found this solution and it works really well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856159/double-clicking-on-uitabbarcontrollers-tab-goes-to-root-of-navigation-controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possibility  would be to create a subclass of `UITabBarController` and to implement the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol. 
Then you could implement

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

and return `NO`, when the particular viewController is selected again.
A way to do this is is to save the recently selected item and to compare it with the currently selected one.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on my answer, I'm way too tired to be answering questions right now.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this issue at the weekend.  I kept finding my custom TabBarController was nil during appDelegate didfinishlaunching() method.

The way I got around it was to make my custom TabBarController a UITabBarControllerDelegate and then implemented the following delegate method withint he custom TabBarController class:

```
    // Stops View Controllers from being dismissed when a tab is selected on the UITabBarController
    public func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    return viewController != tabBarController.selectedViewController
    }
```